# Prove that a group has injective homomorphism into direct product of quotients

Tags: group-theory

Herstein problem 2.13.10

> Let $G$ be a group, $K_1,..,K_n$ normal subgroups of $G$. Suppose that $K_1\cap K_2\cap...\cap K_n=(e)$. Let $V_i=G/K_i$. Prove that there is an isomorphism of $G$ into $V_1\times V_2\times .. \times V_n$

I tried to prove $G$ is isomorphic to internal direct product of $V_i$'s but this will give an isomorphism *onto* $V_1\times V_2\times .. \times V_n$ while we are asked to prove merely *into*.

I am unable to deal with two concepts together: external direct product and quotient group. Please give a hint. Please do not give the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The embedding: $$g\mapsto (gK_1, gK_2,...).$$

Comment: Thanks. But I did not expect such concrete hint. You directly gave the isomorphism. Now to verify this is indeed isomorphism is routine. But this hint gives no idea how to approach the problem. How will I develop my thinking, then? This is the problem I often encounter on this forum. Any suggestion how to ask for the hint which gives an idea to approach the problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is not an isomorphism. This is an injective homomorphism. Every map from $G$ to the direct product should map an element to a vector of cosets. The map in the answer is the most natural such.

Comment: @VinayDeshpande After you have seen a few examples (which is a job for the teacher or the book you are reading), you will always try the canonical map when dealing with quotients of groups of any kind. If that happens to not work, you try something else, but that would depend on the problem.

Comment: @JCAA Just to clarify, Herstein defines isomorphism as injective homomorphism (not necessary onto).

Comment: If so, Herstein is wrong.

Comment: @JCAA A definition cannot be wrong, only non-standard, and standards change.

Comment: Herstein was wrong for giving this definition. The reason was probably that he typed his books on a typewriter or wrote them by hand and then a secretary typed.

Comment: For what its worth, I read "...isomorphism of $G$ into..." to mean an embedding/injection.

Comment: @JCAA I don't believe that. I am sure Herstein wrote what he intended to write, but usage has changed since the book was written.

Comment: @DerekHolt: are you saying that Burnside, van der Waerden, Bourbaki and Lang defined isomorphism that way? Of course Herstein wrote what he wanted. He was protected by the First Amendment .

Comment: I have just checked the book, and the definition of isomorphism I found is the "usual" one (p68, 3rd edition). On the other hand, I cannot find the question asked above so cannot verify the wording.

Comment: Herstein wrote at least two books.

Comment: As a side note, there is not just one Herstein's: under this respect, his Topics in Algebra differs from (his own as well) Abstract Algebra.

Comment: My comment above was about Abstract Algebra, which apparently is the more modern one.

Comment: The third edition!